# How to mock $() using jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, sinon, jestjs

We are getting an elementId which passed as a parameter to the $() as below

`var $elementId = $('#' + elementId);`

Is it possible to mock the above statement using jest without including sinon or jasmine. We need to check for not null and $elementId.length as continuation using this mock.

Answer (score 1):

You can mock `$` using `var $ = jest.fn()`;

This will make `$` a [jest spy](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-functions.html#mock-property), then you will able to use `toHaveBeenCalledWith` matcher to verify the params that the function has been called with.